# How to open a file in python, search for a word ignoring case, print success of word is found?

Tags: python, python-3.x

You're reading a book by an unfamiliar author and are curious about which country they might be from. You decide to write a program to help you guess this based on the spelling of the words in the book.

Write a program that reads in a word (e.g. colour or color) and checks if it occurs in the file book.txt, printing out  was found in the book. or  was not found in the book..

For example, given the book.txt file:

> Hypothesize ? How was she going to form a
>   hypothesis when she didn't even know what 
>   the rest of the data looked like ?

The problem is that no matter what I have tried I cannot get my code to ignore the case of the word. The provided input word will always be in lowercase, but your program should match in a case insensitive manner.

My Code:

```
word = input("Word to look for: ")
with open('book.txt') as f:
  if word in f:
    print(word,"was found in the book.")
  else:
    print(word,"was not found in the book.")
```

Expected Output:

`Word to look for: hypothesize
hypothesize was found in the book.`

Please keep this as simple as possible. I am still learning via an online program that does not allow importing modules that are not built in.

Comment: Since you're learning, you can learn best if we don't give you a word-by-word answer.  What you need to do is do more than `if word in f`.  You need to actually access each word in f, and call [str.lower](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower) on it.  By doing that, all comparisons will be lowercase to lowercase, effectively making it case insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
word = input("Word to look for: ")
word_lower = word.lower()

with open('book.txt', 'r') as fh:
    data = fh.read().lower()
    if word_lower in data:
        print(word,"was found in the book.")
    else:
        print(word,"was not found in the book.")
```

I just forced both `word` and `data` (file's content) to lowercase `.lower()` so it becoms non-case sensitive.

I didn't update `word` directly but stored lowered string in another variable (`word_lower`) to allow you to print exactly what user inputed.

Comment: Awesome.  I can see exactly where I went wrong.  Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over words in your file and lowercase each for the comparison :

```
wordToMatch = input("Word to look for: ")
with open('book.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       for word in line.split() :
           if word.lower() in wordToMatch :
              print(word,"was found in the book.")
           else:
              print(word,"was not found in the book.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to force the value in the variable into lower case, you don't have to define a new variable, just use the old one and change it. so instead of
`word_lower = word.lower()` Just do `word = word.lower()` or just put `word.lower()` directly into your if statement. This would be much more efficient.